# NeoLoad results send to datadog

Tags: datadog, neoload

I am using the NeoLoad test tool for my project and getting the test results.

however, Looking at how I can send these results to the DataDog dashboard.?

has anyone done this configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very broad but here is the approach I would try:

- Use [neoload-cli to generate JUnit XML results files](https://github.com/Neotys-Labs/neoload-cli#view-results)
- Upload your JUnit files to Datadog using [datadog-ci](https://docs.datadoghq.com/continuous_integration/setup_tests/junit_upload/?tab=linux)
- script those two steps to run after your tests complete (many different ways to do this, and depends heavily on how you are triggering the tests)